# Wordpress migration and htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to migrate a wordpress from http://myoldwebsite.com/blog to http://newwebsite.com/.

I have htaccess file as follows. Am I right if I change

- `RewriteBase /blog/` to `RewriteBase /`
- `RewriteRule . /blog/index.php` to `RewriteRule . /index.php`

My .htaccess code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a migration plugin, like [WP Migrate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/), to export the DB.
After you are done with the DB import, don't forget to go to Settings->Permalinks and just hit save button, in order to have `.htaccess` updated.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not as simple as just changing the .htaccess file.

From the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change):

> When your domain name or URLs change - i.e. from
>   http://example.com/site to http://example.com, or http://example.com
>   to http://example.net - there are additional concerns. The files and
>   database can be moved, however references to the old domain name or
>   location will remain in the database, and that can cause issues with
>   links or theme display.

The most important change which most trips up a lot of people is to change "siteurl" and "home" in the "wp_options" table to point to your new address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add the following to htaccess file. If you are migrate a wordpress from http://myoldwebsite.com/blog to http://myoldwebsite.com/

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Note** You have to change URL in database also.

If you want to migrate a wordpress from http://myoldwebsite.com/blog to http://newwebsite.com/. You can use followin plugin to migrate
[Plugin link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)